# MariaDB 10.11 Windows Backup Authentication plugin 'auth_gssapi_client' cannot be loaded

Tags: windows, mariadb, backup

installed MariaDB 10.11 on Windows. Try to do backup using

$ mariabackup --backup --target-dir=F:/backup --user=root  --password=

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/full-backup-and-restore-with-mariabackup/

returns with

Failed to connect to MariaDB server: Authentication plugin 'auth_gssapi_client' cannot be loaded:

But on Mariadb web site it says this plugin is included with 10.11

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you see `auth_gssapi_client.dll` in your installation. `mariabackup` can take a `--plugin-dir` command to point to the path where its installed.

Comment: the plugin is builtin in 10.11, @danblack . All clients are able to login without the .dll. All except mariabackup, which is slightly weirdo, since it is does not use the Connector/C client, but something builtin into the server.

Answer (score 2):

Beginning with MariaDB 10.11 (and MariaDB Connector/C 3.3.8) the client side gssapi authentication plugin is now [statically linked](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-c/commit/6d489dd7ed9c19da44f30c837bb62ee9a80af163) against the client library (which is used by all client tools)

There is one exception which is mariadb-backup - it doesn't use client library but the embedded server library (libmysqld), which is not linked against client gssapi plugin.

I filed an issue ([MDEV-33192](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-33192)) in MariaDB Bug Tracker

Until this bug is fixed there are several workarounds:

1. Install auth_gssapi_client.dll from Connector/C <= 3.3.7 or from Server <= 10.10
2. Use another authentication method, e.g. native_password or ed25519.

Answer (score 1):

Use the correct password. You can login with password as 'root', too,by default. auth_gssapi is only used when the password does not match.